# Tool Box missing from IDE screen

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I can not see Toolbox button on left hand side of my IDE screen while working in Visual Studio 2010. Any Help.

Lalu

Comment: We can't see it on your screen either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably accidentally hid it.

To view it again try:

- *View>>Toolbox*

or, (if you have the default keyboard shortcut)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

[image: Toolbox]

Comment: +1 for View|Toolbox, -1 for keyboard shortcuts which vary according to user preferences.

Comment: @ClickRick I've edited the answer reflecting what you mentioned, i hope its clearer now.